# Load JS script in the app running in local context

Tags: javascript, uwp, content-security-policy

I have HTML/JS based UWP application. The app is running in local context, so my "Start page" in package manifest contains: `index.html`.

`index.html` contains following line:

```
<script src="ms-appdata:///temp/myScript.js"></script>
```

So `myScript` is placed in temporary (TempState) folder. I am aware that files in the temp folder can be deleted by system anytime.

When I launch the app I can see following error:

`CSP14312: Resource violated directive 'script-src ms-appx: 'unsafe-eval' blob:' in Host Defined Policy: ms-appdata:///temp/myScript.js. Resource will be blocked.`

I know that when I switch to web context by using `ms-appx-web`, it will work, however, is there any other way to load any JS script in the app running in local context?

UPDATE:
I just forgot to point out that the script is provided by somebody else and cannot be included in the app package.

Comment: wouldn't simply changing the `src` attribute work to point to a different location where you want your `myScript.js` to be located?

Answer (score 0):

This is a CSP error, it's not quite relevant to the web/local context. You need to configure your CSP in `<meta/>` tag on the `index.html`. Please see the [Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP)
 for more details.

Comment: Could you please give me a hint what exactly should be there?

Comment: The CSP error says 'script-src', you should check [CSP: script-src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src).